# Trying to get Weekday using NSDateComponents but weekday always the same

Tags: ios6, xcode4, nsdateformatter, nsdatecomponents

I'm trying to obtain the day of the week using the code below with a variable NSString. Whatever value I use the weekday always comes back as 2. What am I doing wrong?

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"EEE, dd MMM yyyy"];
NSString *stringDate = @"23/05/2013";
NSDate *dateStr = [dateFormatter dateFromString:stringDate ];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *weekdayComponents =[gregorian components:NSWeekdayCalendarUnit fromDate:dateStr];
gWeekday = [weekdayComponents weekday];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The date format does not match your string. With

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSString *stringDate =       @"23/05/2013";
```

you get the correct result.